# Excecute parallel promises inside for each

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I am trying to execute a set of promises A,B,C,D inside a forEach. These promises should be executed sequentially for all the list items, in parallel. I expect the execution to wait until all the promises are resolved. But as soon the first promise inside the forEach is encountered, the flow starts processing the other functions in parallel.
In the code snippet below, after all promises inside the list are resolved, then thirdCall should be triggered. However, it still doesn't work

```
async function getList(value) {
  return someList;
}

async function processList(list) {
  try {
    await list.forEach(async (element) => {
      await A(element.firstProperty); // console jumps to thirdCall() while executing A,B,C,D in parallel
      await B(element.secondProperty);
      await C(element.thirdProperty);
      await D(element.fourthProperty);
    });
    return response;
  } catch (e) {
    throw (e);
  }
}

async function thirdCall() {
  try {
    let someresult = someProcessing(); // this should start execution ONLY AFTER processList() is done.
    await E(someresult);
    thirdCallResponse;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(`error deleting policy ${error}`);
    throw error;
  }
}

async function processValue(value) {
  try {
    const list = await getList(value);
    await processList(list);
    await thirdCall(value);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}

processValue('someGuid');
```

Comment: Return a mapped array of Promises inside a `Promise.all` instead. Or, if you wanted serial execution, `await` inside a `for` loop instead

Comment: all the list items should be processed in parallel. The promises A,B,C,D should be exectued in sequence hence are await is used for them.

Comment: `return Promise.all(list.map(async (element) => { await A( ...`